# Poor Performance Using DOM from JAXB

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb, saxon

I am experiencing extremely poor performance using a DOM marshaled from JAXB.  To make a long story short when I do an XSL transformation using a DOM created with an XML file as its source  it takes about 30 seconds.  Doing the same transformation using a DOM created by marshaling the JAXB structure to DOM takes about 2 hours.  No exaggeration.  What is especially interesting is that the XML file source is from toString-ing the DOM created from JAXB so the same objects are being handled.

I am using Saxon 9HE, Xerces 2.11 and JAXB 2.1.9.

I profiled both cases and the most interesting thing I find is that the file-sourced DOM hits the method net.sf.saxon.tree.util.Navigator$DescendantEnumeration.advance() around 16.5 million times.  The JAXB-source DOM called it over 4.5 *billion* times before I killed it.  Clearly, something is different.

Of course there is a lot more information behind this, but I am wondering if this rings a bell with anyone and whether there is an obvious answer that I have not found.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't tell from this description why there should be quite such an extreme difference. However, generally, Saxon is slow when processing the DOM and it's much better to let it build the tree in its own native format (often ten times faster). If you've got lexical XML and you want to use Saxon on it, then give Saxon a SAXSource or StreamSource, don't build a DOM.

Comment: There isn't anything special about the DOM build by JAXB.  Can you inspect the underlying impl of the two DOMs to ensure they're the same?

Comment: Any chance of putting together a repro and submitting it on the Saxon forum at http://saxonica.plan.io -?

Comment: Not very simply, unfortunately.  The JAXB structure is built from a large DB schema so a great deal of code and setup would be needed.  I will add more information shortly that I hope will help.